How do I create symbols for input/output?
I'm thinking of something like this: 

are  they in fontawesome5?

@daleif Yes, they're called sign-in and sign-out (or the -alt versions).   However, I don't know how to use font-awesome

@NeilG `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\faIcon{sign-in-alt}
\end{document}`

texdoc comprehensive

@cfr I combed through symbols-a4, but couldn't find anything.

@NeilG hmm. it has e.g. \faSignIn but seems it may not cover fontawesome5 ...


As someone in the comments said: You use the fontawesome5 package and the command \faIcon{sign-in-alt} or \faIcon{sign-out-alt} to get the symbols. You can combine them with the contour and shadowtext package to change them up. To get a bold version, you can use \contour*{black}{ }.
Here is the MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{shadowtext}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\faInput}{\faIcon{sign-in-alt}}
\newcommand{\faOutput}{\faIcon{sign-out-alt}}

\begin{document}

\faInput,
\contour*{black}{\faInput}, 
\textcolor{green}{\faInput}, 
\contour{black}{\textcolor{yellow}{\faInput}},
\shadowtext{\faInput},
\shadowtext{\contour{black}{\textcolor{pink}{\faInput}}}\par

\faOutput,
\contour*{black}{\faOutput},
\contour{red}{\textcolor{lime}{\faOutput}},
etc.

\end{document}

I tried to change the color of the shadow with \setshadowcolor{0.66, 0.66, 1} as shown here, but I got an error, so I couldn't replicate the colored shadow on the last image in your post.

Well try and good attempt

You can use directly \pdfliteral for creating this simple image. The advantage is that you can select the weight of the character by arbitrary decimal number. I used weights 5, 4, 3, 2 in order to the result be similar as in your image.
\newdimen\iocharwd \iocharwd=40bp
\def\inputchar#1#2{% #1 = scale factor (1 means 40bp x 40bp), #2 = weight
   \hbox to#1\iocharwd{\pdfliteral{
      q 1 j 1 J #2 w #1 0 0 #1 0 0 cm  1 0 0 1 5 0 cm
      15 40 m 20 40 l 30 40 30 40 30 30 c 30 10 l 30 0 30 0 20 0 c 15 0 l S
      0 20 m 20 20 l 10 10 l S 20 20 m 10 30 l S Q
   }\vbox to#1\iocharwd{}\hss}}

\def\outputchar#1#2{% #1 = scale factor (1 means 40bp x 40bp), #2 = weight
   \hbox to#1\iocharwd{\pdfliteral{
      q 1 j 1 J #2 w #1 0 0 #1 0 0 cm  1 0 0 1 5 0 cm
      15 40 m 10 40 l 0 40 0 40 0 30 c 0 10 l 0 0 0 0 10 0 c 15 0 l S
      10 20 m 30 20 l 20 10 l S 30 20 m 20 30 l S Q
   }\vbox to#1\iocharwd{}\hss}}

\noindent
\outputchar{.3}{5} \outputchar{.3}{4} \outputchar{.3}{3} \outputchar{.3}{2}

\medskip

\noindent
\inputchar{.3}{5} \inputchar{.3}{4} \inputchar{.3}{3} \inputchar{.3}{2}

\bye

The \pdfliteral is pdfTeX primitive. If you are using luaTeX then define \protected\def\pdfliteral{\pdfextension literal} (if it isn't done by used macros).


+1 Can you recommend some introduction to using \pdfliteral?

@campa The PDF format uses shortcuts of original PostScript commands. The PostScrit names of these commands are more understandable: m moveto, l lineto, c curveto, S stroke, q begin, Q end, w linewidth, J type of line ends (1=rounded), j type of line connections (1=rounded).

This is amazing.  I'm just curious, but which is more efficient for a pdf file, or are they the same?  Using a font character, or this mini-program?

@NeilG This is good question. The mini-programs for characters from the real font are loaded only once to the pdf file and their usage is realized by pointers (character codes). It means that although they are used repeatedly then the size of the resulting pdf file is kept small. On the other hand, the \pdfliteral puts its mini-program repeatedly to the PDF file. If you want to use these "characters" really many times then the PDF code should be modified by creating a single PDF object and using pointer to this object when the "character" is used.

Awesome, thanks for explaining.  If you have time, would love to see the code for that.

Adding to Vebjorn's nice answer: You can create a colored shadow by copying the glyph in a zero-sized box which is shifted a bit:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\faInput}{\faIcon{sign-in-alt}}
\newcommand{\faOutput}{\faIcon{sign-out-alt}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\offsetshadow}{ O{.1ex} m m }{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace*{#1}\raisebox{-#1}{\color{#2}#3}}#3%
}

\begin{document}

\faInput,
\offsetshadow{cyan}{\faInput},
\offsetshadow{red!50}{\faInput}

\faOutput,
\offsetshadow{cyan}{\faOutput},
\offsetshadow{red!50}{\faOutput}

\end{document}


